# htaccess redirect all inside domain but keep images

Tags: .htaccess

I have parkeddomain.com and maindomain.net ( which setup when config server )
the website  run on parkeddomain.com for every think

now i need to redirect all request to maindomain.com to the parkeddomain.com

so far i got

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.maindomain.net$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.parkeddomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But only domain redirect, the internal pages/ subfolder not redirect !!

And also I need for cookieless speed purpose, static/images files I need keep the images url 
not redirect

eg: `www.maindomain.net/sample.html` will need redirect to `www.parkeddomain.com/sample.html`

but `www.maindomain.net/images/abc.jpg` not redirect to any where

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.maindomain.net$
RewriteRule (.*)\.jpg - [L]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.parkeddomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The following rule says that if the url ends in `.jpg` then don't do anything. the `-` says do nothing and `[L]` says this should be the last rule to be followed, so it ignore any following rules.

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.jpg - [L]
```

If you want multiple image extension then you can use something similar to:

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png) - [L]
```

Comment: i have tried all posible way but still not work.. only root domain redirected .. other page still not chagne.. please have look at: http://jsfiddle.net/4QGEP/1/  and go to line config for xaluan.org ..

Comment: i have retest again strange is it redirect with php files like xaluan.org/thanhtoan.php?pay=1  but not work with html or images file /bloon.html .. .. SO if dont need to config for RewriteRule (.*)\.jpg - [L] it still work.. Beside I i put that config in server will down in loop redirect forever.. got no ideal !